# Next.Js/React.Js how to redirect user to login page when he is not logged in?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am using Next.Js to create my App (I use it because I like the file routing) and I can't figure out how to properly redirect user to /login page when he visits the page and is not authenticated.  ( I am trying to create my own system so I do not use any auth libraries )

The user can register and login normaly, when he logges in he receives a JWT token from a seperate Express.Js server, however I can't figure out how to redirect the user to /login page when he visits the page.

When I use `router.push("/login")` in the useEffect(() => .... ) it throws me this error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error

SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
```

And in the console:

```
 1. Too many calls to Location or History APIs within a short timeframe.
 2. Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The operation is insecure.
```

This is my UserSession.tsx:

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

interface LoginData {
  "token": string, 
  "user_id": string,
  "username": string,
  "first_name": string,
  "last_name": string,
  "profile_picture": string
}

interface IUserSessionContext {
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
  username: string;
  login: (data: LoginData) => void;
  logout: () => void;
}

const UserSessionContext = createContext<IUserSessionContext>({
  isLoggedIn: false,
  username: "",
  login: () => {},
  logout: () => {}
});

const UserSessionProvider = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState<string>("");
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if user has token
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const userData = localStorage.getItem('userData');
        
    if (token && userData) {
      const parsedData: LoginData = JSON.parse(userData);
      setUsername(parsedData.username);
      setIsLoggedIn(true)
    } 
  }, []);

  const login = useCallback((data: LoginData) => {
    const userData: LoginData = data;

    setUsername(userData.username);
    setIsLoggedIn(true)

    localStorage.setItem('token', userData.token);
    localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(userData));

    router.push("/");
  }, [router]);

  const logout = useCallback(() => {
    const name = "";
    const loggedIn = false;

    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    localStorage.removeItem('userData');

    setUsername(name);
    setIsLoggedIn(loggedIn);

    router.push("/login");
  }, [router]);

  return { username, isLoggedIn, login, logout}
};

export { UserSessionProvider, UserSessionContext };
```

And this is my _app.tsx:

```
import { UserSessionContext, UserSessionProvider } from '@/components/context/UserSession'
import PageHeader from '@/components/PageHeader'
import UserSideBar from '@/components/UserSideBar'
import '@/styles/globals.css'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Script from 'next/script'
import { useContext, useEffect } from 'react'

type AppProps = {
  Component: React.ComponentType<any>,
  pageProps: any
}

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const userSessionData = useContext(UserSessionContext);

  const pageToRender = () => {
    if (router?.pathname === '/login' || router?.pathname === '/register') {
      return <Component {...pageProps} />
    } else {
      return (
        <>
          <UserSideBar />
          <div className='pageContent'>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </div>
        </>
      )
    }
  }

  const { username, isLoggedIn, login, logout  } = UserSessionProvider();

  useEffect(() => {

    if(!userSessionData.isLoggedIn){
        router.push("/login")
    }
        
  })


  return (
    <UserSessionContext.Provider value={{ username, isLoggedIn, login, logout }}>
      <PageHeader />
      {pageToRender()}
    </UserSessionContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `useCallback` in your login and logout function?

Comment: You should add a dependency to the useEffect of _app as well!